# Python Selenium Webdriver - Grab div after specified one

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Python Selenium Firefox Webdriver to grab the h2 content 'My Data Title' from this HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li class="live">
            <span>
                Section Details
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <h2>
        My Data Title
    </h2>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li class="live">
            <span>
                Another Section
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <h2>
        Another Title
    </h2>
</div>
```

Each div has a class of **box** so I can't easily identify the one I want.  Is there a way to tell Selenium to grab the h2 in the box class that comes after the one that has the span called **'Section Details'**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want grab the `h2` in the box class that comes after the one that has the span with text `Section Details` try below `xpath` using `preceding` :-

```
(//h2[preceding::span[normalize-space(text()) = 'Section Details']])[1]
```

or using `following` :

```
(//span[normalize-space(text()) = 'Section Details']/following::h2)[1]
```

and for `Another Section` just change the span text in `xpath` as:-

```
(//h2[preceding::span[normalize-space(text()) = 'Another Section']])[1]
```

or

```
(//span[normalize-space(text()) = 'Another Section']/following::h2)[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an XPath to select the title following the text "Section Details":

```
//div[@class='box'][normalize-space(.)='Section Details']/following::h2
```

Comment: can you please tell me more about this `normalize-space(.)`?

Comment: @Yu Zhang, it removes the white spaces (line feed, line return ...) and replace any double space by a single space.

Comment: I am attempting to use this like this data = driver.findElement(By.XPATH("//div[@class='box'][normalize-space(.)='Section Details']/following::h2")).getText()) - but am getting an error invalid syntax, any ideas?

Comment: @fightstarr20, your code doesn't look like python. If Java then it should be `By.xpath(`

Answer (score 1):

yeah, you need to do some complicated xpath searching:

```
referenceElementList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span")
for eachElement in referenceElementList:
    if eachElement.get_attribute("innerHTML") == 'Section Details':
        elementYouWant = eachElement.find_element_by_xpath("../../../following-sibling::div/h2")

elementYouWant.get_attribute("innerHTML") should give you "My Data Title"
```

My code reads:

1. find all span elements regardless of where they are in HTML and store them in a list called `referenceElementList`;
2. iterate all `span` elements in `referenceElementList` one by one, looking for a span whose `innerHTML` attribute is '`Section Details`'.
3. if there is a match, we have found the span, and we navigate backwards three levels to locate the enclosing `div[@class='box']`, and find this `div` element next sibling, which is the second `div` element,
4. Lastly, we locate the `h2` element from its parent.

Can you please tell me if my code works? I might have gone wrong somewhere navigating backwards.

**There is potential difficulty you may encounter, the innerHTML attribute may contain tab, new line and space characters, in that case, you need regex to do some filtering first.**